# How to load dynamically a SBT plugin

Tags: sbt

The [sbt-plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git) doesn't work with [git worktrees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).

So I'd like to conditionally load this SBT plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-git" % "0.8.5")
```

add these lines in `plugins.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
    if (baseDirectory.value / "../.git" isDirectory)
        Seq(Defaults.sbtPluginExtra("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-git" % "0.8.5", (sbtBinaryVersion in update).value, (scalaBinaryVersion in update).value))
    else {
        println("sbt-git plugin not loaded")
        Seq.empty
    }
}
```

Tested with SBT 0.13.9.

**UPDATE**:

It works also with SBT 1.7.1, with a slightly different syntax:

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
    if (baseDirectory.value / "../.git" isDirectory)
        Seq(Defaults.sbtPluginExtra("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-git" % "0.8.5", (update/sbtBinaryVersion).value, (update/scalaBinaryVersion).value))
    else {
        println("sbt-git plugin not loaded")
        Seq.empty
    }
}
```